# Three columned UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I make a UITableViewCell with three columns in this format:

|Text=======xxx===yy%|

where "|" represents the end of the cells and "=" is spacing. "Text" is any text, "xxx" is some integer, and "yy%" is some percent.

Right now, I have this format:

|Text==============xxx| using this code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
BOOL inthere = NO;
if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
```

and then later in that method:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = str2;
cell.textLabel.text = str1;
```

But I'd like to add another column towards the end. Does anyone know how to achieve this "three column" sort of style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override `UITableViewCell` and write your own customize cell.

here is a tutorial :
http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284
for implementing custem cell;

instead of using their custom cell class
go to xcode and make new file, choose objective-C class and in the drop box choose
subclass of uitableviewcell, that will give you nice template to work with.

Comment: I tried the tutorial but I can't seem to get it working with what I need. Can you show me how the code would look for the CustomCell class and then how the code would look for creating the cell?

Comment: The tutorial includes a method "- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier" in the CustomCell class and in that method the line " if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])" is giving me a warning saying that initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier is deprecated. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` to build your custom cells and use those. Either add three `UILabel`s (more convenient) to it or draw everything yourself in `drawRect:` (faster).

Comment: Would you mind showing me the code for this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to have a custom cell.

Have a look at Apple's *[TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)* for an overview.

Most likely [subclassing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12) is your way to go.

[TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) is a sample code project, that shows the different ways to create custom cells.